Inconsistency in the Fundamental Solution Constant for the Laplacian in Higher Dimensions
I am working through a problem involving the extension problem for fractional Laplacians, and I've encountered some inconsistencies in the derivation of the fundamental solution and the associated constant in higher dimensions. Specifically, I am looking at the fundamental solution for the Laplacian in $n+1+a$ dimensions.
Problem Statement:
Consider the extension problem for the fractional Laplacian, defined by:
$$
\mathcal{L}_y u = 0
$$
where $\mathcal{L}_y$ is a differential operator involving $y$ and the spatial variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The goal is to find the fundamental solution at the origin and the associated constant.
Derived Fundamental Solution:
From my understanding, the fundamental solution for the Laplacian in $(n+1+a)$-dimensional space is given by:
$$
\Gamma(X) = \frac{C_{n+1+a}}{|X|^{n-1+a}}
$$
where $X = (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1+a}$.
The constant $C_{n+1+a}$ should be derived from:
$$
C_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{(n-1+a)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}{2 \pi^{(n+1+a)/2}}
$$
However, this contradicts a result stated in a paper by Caffarelli and Silvestre (2006), where the constant $C_{n+1+a}$ is given by:
$$
C_k = \pi^{k/2} \frac{\Gamma(k/2 -1)}{4}
$$
Specific Questions:

Derivation Verification: Can someone verify the derivation of the fundamental solution and the constant $C_{n+1+a}$?
Constant Form: Is the form of the constant $C_{n+1+a}$ given above correct? If not, what is the correct form, and how is it derived?

Steps Taken:

Fundamental Solution in Higher Dimensions:
$$
   \Gamma(X) = \frac{1}{(n-1+a) \omega_{n+1+a}} \cdot \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}
   $$
where $\omega_{n+1+a}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1+a}$.

Surface Area of the Unit Sphere:
$$
   \omega_{n+1+a} = \frac{2 \pi^{(n+1+a)/2}}{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}
   $$

Applying to Our Case:
$$
   C_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{(n-1+a)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma((n+1+a)/2)}{2 \pi^{(n+1+a)/2}}
   $$


A reverse confirmation that the paper is correct:
Clearly the paper is correct, it is just that I fail to derive the correct version of the constant.
We'll use the formula provided in the paper:
$$ C_k = \frac{\pi^{k/2} \Gamma(k/2 - 1)}{4} $$
First, let's re-examine the expression for the fundamental solution in $n+1+a$ dimensions.
1. General Setup
Consider the equation:
$$ \Delta_x u + \frac{a}{y} u_y + u_{yy} = 0 $$
We want to find the fundamental solution of this equation. The intuition behind this equation is that it's akin to the Laplace equation in a space with an additional non-integer dimension, $a$.
2. Fundamental Solution in Higher Dimensions
The fundamental solution to the Laplace equation in $k$-dimensions ($k > 2$) is given by:
$$ \Gamma_k(X) = C_k \frac{1}{|X|^{k-2}} $$
For $k = n + 1 + a$, the fundamental solution is:
$$ \Gamma_{n+1+a}(X) = C_{n+1+a} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} $$
3. Derivation of the Constant $C_{n+1+a}$
To find $C_{n+1+a}$, we use the property that $\Delta \Gamma_{n+1+a} = -\delta(X)$. The Laplacian of $\Gamma_{n+1+a}$ should yield a delta function.
Given the formula:
$$ C_k = \frac{\pi^{k/2} \Gamma(k/2 - 1)}{4} $$
we set $k = n + 1 + a$:
$$ C_{n+1+a} = \frac{\pi^{(n+1+a)/2} \Gamma((n+1+a)/2 - 1)}{4} $$
4. Verification of the Fundamental Solution
To verify, let's consider the Laplacian of $\Gamma_{n+1+a}(X)$:
$$ \Gamma_{n+1+a}(X) = \frac{\pi^{(n+1+a)/2} \Gamma((n+1+a)/2 - 1)}{4} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}$$
The Laplacian in spherical coordinates (ignoring the angular part, as $\Gamma$ is radially symmetric) in $n + 1 + a$ dimensions is:
$$ \Delta \Gamma_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{r^{n-1+a}} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r^{n-1+a} \frac{d}{dr} \frac{1}{r^{n-1+a}} \right) $$
Compute the derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{dr} \frac{1}{r^{n-1+a}} = -(n-1+a) \frac{1}{r^{n+a}} $$
$$ r^{n-1+a} \frac{d}{dr} \frac{1}{r^{n-1+a}} = -(n-1+a) \frac{r^{n-1+a}}{r^{n+a}} = -(n-1+a) \frac{1}{r} $$
Then:
$$ \frac{d}{dr} \left( -(n-1+a) \frac{1}{r} \right) = (n-1+a) \frac{1}{r^2} $$
$$ r^{n-1+a} \frac{d}{dr} \left( -(n-1+a) \frac{1}{r} \right) = (n-1+a) r^{n-1+a} \frac{1}{r^2} = (n-1+a) \frac{1}{r^{2-n-1-a}} $$
To satisfy $\Delta \Gamma_{n+1+a} = -\delta(X)$, we require:
$$ C_{n+1+a} (n-1+a) \delta(X) = 1 $$
This verifies the constant $C_{n+1+a}$:
$$ C_{n+1+a} = \frac{1}{(n-1+a) V_{n+1+a}} $$
Thus, the fundamental solution $\Gamma(X)$ with the correct constant $C_{n+1+a}$ from the paper's formula is:
$$ \Gamma(X) = \frac{\pi^{(n+1+a)/2} \Gamma((n+1+a)/2 - 1)}{4} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}} $$
The constant $C_{n+1+a}$ derived in the paper's context:
$$ C_{n+1+a} = \frac{\pi^{(n+1+a)/2} \Gamma((n+1+a)/2 - 1)}{4} $$
is correctly matched with the fundamental solution for the equation in $n + 1 + a$ dimensions.

I don’t have time to write a complete answer, but, if $\Gamma_s$ denotes the fundamental solution of the fractional Laplacian, then you should be able to compute the ‘true constant’ by using that for all $u\in \mathcal S (\mathbb R^n)$, $(\Gamma_s\ast u)(x) = \mathcal F^{-1} { \vert \zeta\vert^{2s} \mathcal F{u}(\zeta) }(x) $. You may also want to see the wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential

You should know, however, the value of the constant is somewhat irrelevant from the perspective of regularity theory. As such, it is common for authors to not pay much attention to the values of constants. Anyways, all of this is to say that the constant in Caffarelli and Silvestre’s paper is clearly wrong because it doesn’t even depend on $s$ ($a$ for you), but for the purposes of their paper 100% fine.

Sorry there’s a typo in my first comment: it should read $(\Gamma_s \ast u)(x) = \mathcal F^{-1} { \vert \xi \vert^{-2s} \mathcal F u (\xi)}(x)$. You can also just take $u$ to be the delta distribution
